# Pandas multiindex: get level values without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

So I'm sure this is pretty trivial but I'm pretty new to python/pandas.

I want to get a certain column (Names of my measurements) of my Multiindex as a list to use it in a for loop later to name and save my plots. I'm pretty confident in getting the data I need from my dataframe but i can't figure out how to get certain columns from my index.

So actually while writing the question I kind of figured the answer out but it still seems kind of clunky. There has to be a direct command to do this.
That would be my code:

```
a = df.index.get_level_values('File')
a = a.drop_duplicates()
a = a.values
```

Comment: df.index.unique('File')

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### index.levels

You can access unique elements of each level of your `MultiIndex` directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'W', 1], ['B', 'X', 2], ['C', 'Y', 3],
                   ['D', 'X', 4], ['E', 'Y', 5]])
df = df.set_index([0, 1])

a = df.index.levels[1]

print(a)
Index(['W', 'X', 'Y'], dtype='object', name=1)
```

To understand the information available, see how the `Index` object is stored internally:

```
print(df.index)

MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['W', 'X', 'Y']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]],
           names=[0, 1])
```

However, the below methods are more intuitive and better documented.

One point worth noting is you don't have to explicitly extract the NumPy array via the `values` attribute. You can iterate `Index` objects directly. In addition, method chaining is possible and encouraged with Pandas.

#### drop_duplicates / unique

Returns an `Index` object, with order preserved.

```
a = df.index.get_level_values(1).drop_duplicates()
# equivalently, df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()

print(a)
Index(['W', 'X', 'Y'], dtype='object', name=1)
```

#### set

Returns a `set`. Useful for O(1) lookup, but result is unordered.

```
a = set(df.index.get_level_values(1))

print(a)
{'X', 'Y', 'W'}
```

Comment: Ah ty that simple example at the top made it so much clearer for me how indexes are formated!

Comment: `df.index.levels[1]` is useful but it does not keep the order of the items in that index level(!)

Comment: df.index.levels seems to include dropped columns, even if columns are not visible